# How can I (re-)define language-specific commands (XeTeX, polyglossia)?

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, greek, renewcommand

When I first wrote a very large document with pdfTeX and babel, I defined two commands for (ancient) Greek only:

1. Linebreak is allowed after `\,`:

   ```
   \addto\extrasgreek{%
   \RenewDocumentCommand\,{}{\linebreak[1]\thinspace}}
   ```
2. Compound words which can be etymologized get a hairspace at the joint, the preferred word break is at this point. Command is `\!` (I copied it mainly for the german language command `"|`):

   ```
    \addto\extrasgreek{\let\!\relax%
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\!}{}{\textormath{% \penalty\@M
    \discretionary{-}{}{\kern.01em}%
    \allowhyphens}{}}}
   ```

With

```
\gappto\blockextras@greek{%
  \let\!\relax%
  \NewDocumentCommand{\!}{}{\textormath{% \penalty\@M
      \discretionary{-}{}{\kern.5em}% \kern.01em
      \allowhyphens}{}}}
```

I get

```
./xetex-greek-commands.tex:77: Argument of \!  has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.77 ...νατος. τὸ γὰρ ἀει\!κίνητον \ladd{ἀθάνατον}
                                                  . τὸ δ'\,ἄλλο
Runaway argument?
./xetex-greek-commands.tex:77: Paragraph ended before \!  was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.77 ...νατος. τὸ γὰρ ἀει\!κίνητον \ladd{ἀθάνατον}
                                                  . τὸ δ'\,ἄλλο
```

Without babel, the command don't work any longer. How can I (re-)define them for the Greek parts only? If you TeXify the document you will see that `\!` is used as `\negthinspace`, no linebreaks after `\,`:

```
% uses-*- MODE: latex; TeX-engine: xetex -*-
\RequirePackage{scrwfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{totpages}
\listfiles
\documentclass[DIV=4]{scrartcl}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{xpatch} % xpatch causes problems with large environments
\PassOptionsToPackage{activate={nocompatibility,true},%
                 expansion=false,final,verbose=silent}{microtype}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[twothirds,nonegthinspace]{thinsp}
\usepackage{mathtools} % possible conflict with amsmath
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xunicode-addon}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,%
                 babelshorthands]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\defaultfontfeatures+[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Ligatures={TeX,Common}}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}[Extension=.otf,%
                              UprightFont= *-Regular,%
                              BoldFont=*-Bold,%
                              ItalicFont=*-Italic,%
                              BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic%
                              ]
\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Porson}[Mapping=tex-text,AutoFakeBold,
                                     AutoFakeSlant=.15,%
                                     Scale=MatchUppercase%
                                     ]
\newfontfamily\latinfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}[Extension=.otf,%
                                          UprightFont= *-Regular,%
                                          BoldFont=*-Bold,%
                                          ItalicFont=*-Italic,%
                                          BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic
                                          ]
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf{GFSNeohellenic}[Mapping=tex-text,
                                           Extension=.otf,%
                                           UprightFont=*,%
                                           BoldFont=*Bold,%
                                           ItalicFont=*It,%
                                           BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,%
                                           Scale=MatchUppercase
                                           ]
\usepackage{microtype}
\makeatletter
% from teubner.sty which I can no longer use with XeTeX and polyglossia; here I employ negthinspace 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Ladd}[1]{{\latinfont\textlangle}%
  {\negthinspace%
    #1\/}{\latinfont\textrangle}}% litterae certe addendae
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ladd}[1]{{\kern.15ex[\negthinspace}%
  {#1\/}{%\metricsfont
    ]\kern-.15ex}} % litterae addendae
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lbrk}{{\latinfont%
    \posthindspace[\negthinspace}}
%-----old definitions----%
\addto\extrasgreek{%
  \RenewDocumentCommand\,{}{\linebreak[1]\thinspace}}
\addto\extrasgreek{\let\!\relax%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\!}{}{\textormath{% \penalty\@M
      \discretionary{-}{}{\kern.01em}%
      \allowhyphens}{}}}
\addto\extrasgreek{\RenewDocumentCommand{\|}{}{\textbar}}
%------------------------%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
bla bla, some english text

\begin{greek}
  Ψυχὴ πᾶσα ἀθάνατος. τὸ γὰρ ἀει\!κίνητον \ladd{ἀθάνατον}. τὸ δ'\,ἄλλο
  κινοῦν καὶ ὑπ'\,ἄλλου κινούμενον, παῦλαν ἔχον κινήσεως, παῦλαν ἔχει
  ζωῆς. μόνον δὴ τὸ αὑτὸ κινοῦν, ἅτε οὐκ ἀπο\!λεῖπον ἑαυτό, οὔ\!ποτε
  λήγει \Ladd{κινούμενον}, ἀλλὰ καὶ τοῖς ἄλλοις ὅσα κινεῖται τοῦτο
  πηγὴ καὶ ἀρχὴ κινήσεως. ἀρχὴ δὲ ἀγένητον. ἐξ ἀρχῆς γὰρ ἀνάγκη πᾶν τὸ
  γι\!γνόμενον γί\!γνεσθαι, αὐτὴν δὲ μηδ'\,ἐξ ἑνός. εἰ γὰρ ἔκ του ἀρχὴ
  γί\!γνοιτο, οὐκ ἂν ἐξ ἀρχῆς γί\!γνοιτο. ἐπει\!δὴ δὲ ἀγένητόν ἐστιν,
  καὶ ἀδιά\!φθορον αὐτὸ ἀνάγκη εἶναι.
\end{greek}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, the `polyglossia` equivalent would be `\gappto\blockextras@greek`.

Comment: why don't you continue to use babel?

Comment: True, there's always that alternative. :) I personally tend to prefer it as well, but I don't really know well why...

Comment: @gusbrs I've included your proposal at the beginning of my question. TeX complains about the `extra }` and a `Runaway argument`.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann Did you surround it with `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`?

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, I did. See above.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann Well, then I don't know what might be going on. I don't have your fonts, so it's hard to try your MWE, and it is also more complex than I'd be willing to unravel right now. It seems that both `\textormath` and `\allowhyphens` are provided by `babel`, so not available without it. But this is actually not the problem with the error you find, since even removing them from the definition does not improve things. You may always follow the good advice of Ulrike.

Comment: Still, as far as I was able to try your MWE, the problem would occur even with `babel`. So it seems you are not telling us the whole story.

Comment: @gusbrs Yes and no. It's partly a problem of `\NewDocumentCommand` without an argument. So I combined your `\gappto\blockextras@greek` with `\newrobustcmd` from `etoolbox` instead of `\NewDocumentCommand` -- and it works!

Comment: it looks definitively wrong to put a \newwhatever inside a command that is executed at every language switch. And the `\let\!\relax` to avoid the error from it, looks like a rather bad hack.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer At least it works perfectly fine. No more errors and warnings.

Comment: Why don't you use `\renew...` or a simple \def or \protected\def instead?

Answer (score 1):

Combining @gusbrs's `\gappto\blockextras@greek` with @Ulrike Fischer's `\let`, I finally got it working:

```
% uses-*- MODE: latex; TeX-engine: xetex -*-
\RequirePackage{scrwfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{totpages}
\listfiles
\documentclass[DIV=4]{scrartcl}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{xpatch}
\PassOptionsToPackage{activate={nocompatibility,true},%
                 expansion=false,final,verbose=silent}{microtype}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[twothirds% ,nonegthinspace
]{thinsp}
\usepackage{mathtools} % possible conflict with amsmath
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xunicode-addon}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,%
                 babelshorthands]{german}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\defaultfontfeatures+[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Ligatures={TeX,Common}}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}[Extension=.otf,%
                              UprightFont= *-Regular,%
                              BoldFont=*-Bold,%
                              ItalicFont=*-Italic,%
                              BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic%
                              ]
\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Porson}[Mapping=tex-text,Language=Greek,AutoFakeBold,
                                     AutoFakeSlant=.15,%
                                     Scale=MatchUppercase%
                                     ]
\newfontfamily\latinfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}[Extension=.otf,%
                                          UprightFont= *-Regular,%
                                          BoldFont=*-Bold,%
                                          ItalicFont=*-Italic,%
                                          BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic
                                          ]
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf{GFSNeohellenic}[Mapping=tex-text,Language=Greek,
                                           Extension=.otf,%
                                           UprightFont=*,%
                                           BoldFont=*Bold,%
                                           ItalicFont=*It,%
                                           BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,%
                                           Scale=MatchUppercase
                                           ]
\usepackage{microtype}
\makeatletter
%-------- from teubner.sty ----------%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Ladd}[1]{{\latinfont\textlangle}%
  {\negthinspace%
    #1\/}{\latinfont\textrangle}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ladd}[1]{\kern.15ex[\negthinspace%
  #1\/%
    ]\kern-.15ex} %
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lbrk}{{\latinfont%
    \posthindspace[\negthinspace}}
%------------------------------------%
\gappto\blockextras@greek{%
  \let\!\relax
  \def\!{\textormath{% \penalty\@M
      \discretionary{-}{}{\kern.03em}%
      \allowhyphens}{}}
  \LetLtxMacro\|\textbar
  \def\,{\nolinebreak[1]\thinspace}}
\gappto\inlineextras@greek{%
  \let\!\relax
  \def\!{\textormath{% \penalty\@M
      \discretionary{-}{}{\kern.03em}%
      \allowhyphens}{}}
  \LetLtxMacro\|\textbar
  \def\,{\nolinebreak[1]\thinspace}}
%------------------------%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
bla bla, some english text

\enlargethispage{4\baselineskip}
\begin{greek}
  Ψυχὴ πᾶσα ἀθάνατος. τὸ γὰρ ἀει\!κίνητον \ladd{ἀθάνατον}. τὸ δ'\,ἄλλο
  κινοῦν καὶ ὑπ'\,ἄλλου κινούμενον, παῦλαν ἔχον κινήσεως, παῦλαν ἔχει
  ζωῆς. μόνον δὴ τὸ αὑτὸ κινοῦν, ἅτε οὐκ ἀπο\!λεῖπον ἑαυτό, οὔ\!ποτε
  λήγει \Ladd{κινούμενον}, ἀλλὰ καὶ τοῖς ἄλλοις ὅσα κινεῖται τοῦτο
  πηγὴ καὶ ἀρχὴ κινήσεως. ἀρχὴ δὲ ἀγένητον. ἐξ ἀρχῆς γὰρ ἀνάγκη πᾶν τὸ
  γι\!γνόμενον γί\!γνεσθαι, αὐτὴν δὲ μηδ'\,ἐξ ἑνός. εἰ γὰρ ἔκ του ἀρχὴ
  γί\!γνοιτο, οὐκ ἂν ἐξ ἀρχῆς γί\!γνοιτο. ἐπει\!δὴ δὲ ἀγένητόν ἐστιν,
  καὶ ἀδιά\!φθορον αὐτὸ ἀνάγκη εἶναι. \| βλα
\end{greek}
\end{document}
```